# HTTP 404 in MVC form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I do have a MVC C# form like this

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", id = "FormAgrupar" }))
```

as you can see there is no action nor controller defined just the id value(FormAgrupar) and in the same form I have two checkbox(one for delete row and another one for associate to a specific event) and two buttons

```
<td style="text-align: center">
<input type="checkbox" name="delete" id="delete" value="@item.numero_documento" />
</td>
<td style="text-align: center">
<input type="checkbox" name="code" id="code" value="@item.numero_documento" />
</td>

<input type="button" value="Eliminar Solicitudes" id="btn-eliminar" class="btn btn-danger" />
<input type="button" value="Agrupar Solicitudes" id="btn-agrupar" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
```

when the user clicks any button I capture the click event via jQuery, for the button "Eliminar Solicitudes" this is the code:

```
 var form = $("#FormAgrupar");
                form.attr("action", "@Url.Action("RealizarEliminacion","Home")");
                form.submit();
```

and for the button Agrupar Solicitudes this is the jQuery code:

```
 var form = $("#FormAgrupar");
                form.attr("action", "@Url.Action("RealizarAgrupacion","Home")");
                form.submit();
```

theres is not any problem when I press the button "Agrupar Solicitudes" but when I press the button "Eliminar Solicitudes" I got the message " Server error in '/'  Application - HTTP 404 the resource you are lookin for...Requested url:/Home/RealizarEliminacion" and dont get any clue why, these are my actions in the Home Controller

```
     [Authorize]
            public ActionResult RealizarAgrupacion(string[] code)
            {

 [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RealizarEliminacion(string[] delete)
        {
```

I just added the [HttpPost] because I thought that might solve the problem but nah, so could you please tell me what is the problem?

P.S.  when working this project on development all works just fine but when runs the project in the production enviroment(internet in this case) is when the error prompts.

Comment: I just tried your code without the Authorize tag and it works perfectly, both debuging and installed on IIS, would like to just comment and no answer, but I do not have the minimum requeriments, can you provide your whole html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pablo:

I was able to replicate your behaviour. The error happens when you are not logged in. Because of the `[Authorize]` decorator, the app is forcing you to log in. After you did it, the redirection went to the desired page (/home/RealizarEliminacion in this example), but it's not a POST request, but a GET.
If you log in BEFORE you POST the form, it should work.

Regards

Adrian